# How to make Byte Buddy load many types into the same wrapper class loader

Tags: java, classloader, introspection, byte-buddy, bytecode-manipulation

I'm using Byte Buddy in a scenario in which I could potentially need to create several dozen thousand classes with it. These are independent classes implementing interfaces, not proxies.

Right now I'm loading my `DynamicType.Unloaded<?>` instances into class loaders by wrapping one of my application's class loaders:

```java
final Class<?> myClass =
    unloadedType
        .load(someAppClassLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
        .getLoaded();
```

This wrapping strategy is right for me, but I have the issue that every time I execute the code above a new, sealed `ClassLoader` is created containing only the new class. I know I can "include" auxiliary types... but these are not auxiliary types, but fully independent classes.

As I have to create many thousands, I'm left with a huge amount of class loaders I don't really need, because I want to isolate bytebuddy-created classes from the rest, but not one from the other, nor have any need to have a new class loader created for each one. And my profiling shows quite a huge memory overhead from the large amount of class loaders (which in this case are quite heavy).

From my tests it seems  I could use a wrapping strategy for the first one:

```java
final Class<?> myClass =
    type
        .load(someAppClassLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
        .getLoaded();
```

...then retrieve the new class loader:

```java
final ClassLoader bbClassLoader = myClass.getClassLoader();
```

...and then use this class loader in subsequent creations, by switching strategy to *injection*:

```java
final Class<?> myOtherClass =
    otherUnloadedType
        .load(bbClassLoader, ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION)
        .getLoaded();
```

But this does not look like a *clean* strategy to me given it seems to be injecting via introspection in order to circumvent the fact that the class loader is sealed. So I wonder whether there is a better mechanism for doing this in Byte Buddy.

Note that in order to have a properly *sealed* class loader I could turn all my many thousands of `DynamicType.Unloaded` objects into `Class<?>` ones at once into a single class loader instance (and seal it). I can initialise all my classes at application bootstrap in a batch and then leave the class loader alone without further dynamic class creation.

What would be the proper strategy for a scenario like mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class loader that is created when using a `WRAPPER` strategy allows for loading classes later in the class loader's life-cycle. For security reasons, this needs to be enabled by calling `opened()` on the strategy.

You can then cast the first class loader to `InjectionClassLoader` which allows for using `InjectionClassLoader.Strategy.INSTANCE` where additional classes can be injected without any unsafe API.

You can also combine multiple `DynamicType` instance by calling `include` and then load all classes using `WRAPPER` in one wash.

Comment: Thank you again. Also, the API describes _unsealed_ class loaders as being possible to "break package encapsulation" by anyone getting a ref to the class loader instance. Could you give an example of what you mean with "breaking package encapsulation"? I'm trying to evaluate what risks an "opened()" class loader could have for me...

Comment: Happt to help. if your generated code has package private members, anybody could inject a new class into the opened class loader and access those members.